# Scrapy: excluding some text in the scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy, and have spent ages trying to solve what I think should be two simple questions.

(1) I am trying to scrape this website:

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-vanburen-iraq-commentary/commentary-the-tragedy-of-the-u-s-victory-in-iraq-idUSKBN1FF2XW

Specifically, I am trying to scrape just the article's text (so no pictures, captions, title, etc...). The code I am using is:

```
response.css('div.body_1gnLA p::text').extract()
```

The problem is that at the bottom of the article, there is an "about the author" section that gets included in the scrape, which I do not want. The specific text I do not want is the following:

*"Peter Van Buren, a 24-year State Department veteran, is the author of We Meant Well: How I Helped Lose the Battle for the Hearts and Minds of the Iraqi People and Hooper’s War: A Novel of WWII Japan. @WeMeantWell
The views expressed in this article are not those of Reuters News."*

(2) In the article, some text is hyperlinked. For example, in the first sentence

"Iraqi Prime Minister Haider al-Abadi declared victory over Islamic State on Dec. 9, 2017"

*declared victory* is hyperlinked. When I use the code I wrote above to scrape, it gives me

"Iraqi Prime Minister Haider al-Abadi   over Islamic State on Dec. 9, 2017"

Notice that the hyperlinked part, "declared victory", is missing. How can I fix this? I only want the full sentence's text to be scraped; I don't care about the href part.

Much appreciated if anyone could help!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way:

```
def parse(self, response):

    paragraphs = []

    for p in response.xpath('//div[@class="body_1gnLA"]/p'):
        p_text = p.xpath( 'string(.)' ).extract_first()
        paragraphs.append(p_text)

    article = "\n".join(paragraphs)
    print(article)
```